# Grid in Viewbox does not strech to Viewbox size

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want my whole `Page` to be scalable, so I put my `Grid` into a `Viewbox`.

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

The `Viewbox` streches to the window's size but the problem is that the `Grid` does not. 
Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to experiment with Viewbox's **Stretch** property. Here is my sample:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button Content="Button1" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Button Content="Button2" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Button Content="Button3" Grid.Row="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
```

This gives:

[image]

While a value of **Uniform** gives:
[image]

If you want a uniform fill you may want to wrap your Viewbox with a **ScrollViewer**, this gives a complete uniform fill and with the scroll viewer you can scroll to those parts that you may not see. Like the following picture:

[image]

... and resizing the window to make all controls visible...

[image]

Hope this helps!